# HEROKU proces.env.PORT is different each time run

Tags: node.js, heroku, mern

I build the MERN stack app, now want to deploy with Heroku, But getting errors, I think I know the problem, but don't know how to solve it,
the Heroku process.env.PORT is different every time it runs, and in the frontend package.json file I Have a proxy; set like this,

"proxy": "http://127.0.0.1:5000",

also in the Heroku config var, I have a PORT variable that equals 5000,

I am getting this in when typing Heroku logs

Starting process with command `node backend/server.js`
2021-03-27T20:28:03.878354+00:00 app[web.1]: Server Is Running In production Mode  On Port 24467
2021-03-27T20:28:04.056734+00:00 app[web.1]: MongoDB Connected: obstacle-sports-shard-00-00.f6dsx.mongodb.net
2021-03-27T20:29:01.786347+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
2021-03-27T20:29:01.852333+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2021-03-27T20:29:01.947405+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2021-03-27T20:29:02.009952+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2021-03-27T20:29:56.979844+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=obstaclesports.herokuapp.com request_id=fe4854ea-a770-443b-98c5-2b9d94e2b338 fwd="178.134.230.76" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=http
2021-03-27T20:29:57.527139+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=obstaclesports.herokuapp.com request_id=a7a81f29-55f0-4d22-bf7b-dc0ff89d01e0 fwd="178.134.230.76" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=http

so can anyone help, how to set the default Heroku port on 5000, or how to give the correct URL, to proxy?

Comment: Why do you need to set the proxy? You're not using the Webpack dev server as the production entry point, right?

Comment: var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;     <-- normal for heroku hosted .  In dev ONLY you set the port to 5000.  In Prod, port is set dynamically by heroku and your code should accomdate that fact

Comment: this is what my server.js file looks like, but every time the Heroku ports are different, so I don't know, but the error reason is that in the front end it could not recognize the correct URL, where to send API request            -------- const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000 app.listen(5000, () => { console.log(Server Is Running In ${process.env.NODE_ENV} Mode  On Port ${PORT}.yellow.bold) }) ------

Comment: @jonrsharpe, yes right, so I don't need to set proxy in package,json for production?

Comment: You shouldn't be using the proxy (or Webpack dev server at all) in production. If you're not, then it doesn't matter how it's configured.